# How to properly handle orientation changes in Android ViewModels with RxJava

Tags: android

I am playing with the `ViewModel` of the `Architectural Components` and lets say I have the following `ViewModel`

```
class DummyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        val liveData:MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
        val disposables = CompositeDisposable()
    }

    fun test() {
        disposables.add(
                Observable  // Rxjava 2 Observable
                        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .map { it.toString() }
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe{
                            liveData.value = it
                        }
        )
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        disposables.clear()
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    ....

    val dummyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DummyViewModel::class.java)

    RestaurantViewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer<String> {
        mTextView.text = it
    })

    dummyViewModel.test()
}
```

The problem is that each time I rotate the screen a new Observable is created so I was wondering what is the correct way to handle the observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `if (liveData.value  == null) {` check at start of of `test()`.  Also I don't think you should need `liveData` and `disposables` inside that `companion` block.

I'm doing something similar in following https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/viewmodel/BusStopsViewModel.kt

(am also pretty new to AACs and Kotlin so definitely open to better suggestions as well!)